# change all ampersands in form to tildes before serialize()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms

I'm trying to find an efficient way to convert all ampersands in form inputs to something else (maybe a ~ or something) before `$("#myForm").serialize()`ing a form. The reason for this is that I'm splitting the resulting string on the `&` character, and then the `=` character, to get a list of names and values.

This system works fine, except, obviously, when one of the values contains an ampersand.

I've been trying to think of ways to globally replace all `&`s in a form, but I can't think of anything that seems at all efficient.

Comment: `string.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;')`

Comment: @adeneo That would get rid of the ampersands introduced by `serialize()`, too. If it were that easy, I wouldn't have posted the question :)

Comment: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/URLEncode perhaps?

Comment: I don't understand the why but maybe you can use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of `.serialize()`

Comment: Why not just split on both ?

Comment: @adeneo You may be misunderstanding the question a little. Probably my fault :P When I use serialize(), I get something like this: `var1=x&var2=y&var3=z`, but if there are ampersands in the values, it ends up looking like this: `var1=Tom & Jerry&var2=R&B&var3=Johnson&Johnson`, which breaks my splitting process.

Comment: @Andreas read that ^ for the way

Comment: Why, rather. (Hey look I'm a string which is here just to meet the character minimum)

Comment: Why before? Why don't you serialze and do a `string.split('&amp;').join('~')` after serializing?

Comment: @AakilFernandes well, because the string.split('&amp;') would split on the ampersands from the serialization as well as the ones in the actual values, so it wouldn't work

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt, no it wouldn't split on the ampersands. "&" is not equal to "%26;". "%26" is the urlencoded version of "&" which would be returned by the serialization. If you split by "%26" the standalone "&"s will not be affected.

Edited to change "amp;" to "%26"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
var foo = $("#myForm").serializeArray().map(function(el) {
    return el.name + "=" + el.value.replace(/&/g, "~");
}).join("&");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BMvka/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myForm").serialize().split('%26').join('~')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evWkT/2/